# SOLR/LUCENE Experts, please help me design a simple keyword search from PDF index?

Tags: pdf, lucene, solr, full-text-search, keyword

I dabbled with solr but couldn't figure out a way to tailor it to my reuqirement.

**What I have :**

A bunch of PDF files.
A set of keywords.

**What I am trying to achieve :**

Index the PDF files (solrcell - done)
Search for a keyword (works ok)
Tailor the output to spit out the names of the PDF files, an excerpt where the keyword occurred (No clue/idea how to)

Tried manipulating ResponseHandler/Schema.xml/Solrconfig.xml to no avail.

Lucene/solr experts, do you think what I am trying to achieve is possible?

I put my existing code on github @ https://github.com/ThinkCode/solr_search (which is mostly solr's default example with minor modifications to the fields (all the content is stored in one content field).

Notable changes in schema.xml being :

Schema.xml :

```
<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="AND"/>

   <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />

   <field name="content" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" termVectors="true" termPositions="true" termOffsets="true"/>

   <dynamicField name="*" type="string"    indexed="true"  stored="true" multiValued="true" termVectors="true" termPositions="true" termOffsets="true"/>

<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="AND"/>

<copyField source="*" dest="content"/>
```

Current Output :

> (query) 
>   http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=Java+Servlet&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on

```
<response><lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">0</int><int name="QTime">13</int><lst name="params"><str name="indent">on</str><str name="start">0</str><str name="q">Java Servlet</str><str name="version">2.2</str><str name="rows">10</str></lst></lst>

<result name="response" numFound="1" start="0"><doc><arr name="content_type"><str>application/pdf</str></arr><str name="id">tutorial.pdf</str><str name="subject">Solr</str><arr name="title"><str>Solr tutorial</str></arr></doc></result></response>
```

What I am looking for is 'extracted fragment (line) where the keyword was found'.

In the query provided, I search for 'Java Servlet' and it returned the document. I am interested in the context 'Solr can run in any Java Servlet Container of your choice' to be returned in the output xml.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Can you post what you have so far, or where concretely you're having trouble?

Comment: I put the code on github @ https://github.com/ThinkCode/solr_search and the schema file is at https://github.com/ThinkCode/solr_search/blob/master/apachesolr330/example/solr/conf/schema.xml

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but you'll have to be much more specific than this... otherwise it's a "plz send me the codez / do my job for free" kind of question, which is not welcome on stackoverflow.

Comment: I updated the question with a sample. I am not looking for someone who can do the job for me! I am looking for hints/leads which will help me research in the right direction. Its been less than a week since I stumbled upon solr. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get snippets of text around the matched keywords, see http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters

To get the filename of the indexed PDF as part of the response, simply add a field with that information (it should be a string field, non-indexed, stored). Of course, you have to populate this new field at index-time.

Answer (score 0):

A standalone solution using PDF Box and Apache Lucene is available at:
* https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/pdfindexer
It will create a HTML file with links to the corresponding pages in the PDF file where the keywords were found.